# Use nanogui inside an existing OpenGL project without GLFW

Tags: opengl, glfw

The look and feel of nanogui is very appealing, and it looks like a well designed ui toolset. Is it possible to use it inside an existing project, that does not use GLFW? I had a quick look at the source, and there are some GLFW dependencies indeed, like e.g. (button.cpp)

```
if (button == GLFW_MOUSE_BUTTON_1 && mEnabled) {...}
```

Or is there any other way to mix-in GLFW into an existing OpenGL application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on a quick look at the CMakeLists build instructions, in particular:

```
if (NOT IS_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/ext/glfw/src")
  message(FATAL_ERROR "The NanoGUI dependency repositories (GLFW, etc.) are missing! "
    "You probably did not clone the project with --recursive. It is possible to recover "
    "by calling \"git submodule update --init --recursive\"")
endif()
```

It appears to depend quite heavily on GLFW being the primary framework.  The dependency seems particularly heavy since this is a GUI library, so it's inherently tied to the input system.  You can see, for example, in https://github.com/wjakob/nanogui/blob/master/src/common.cpp that the main loop is fundamentally tied to GLFW (and, perhaps more importantly, the main loop is already defined for you -- I haven't seen if that can be overridden or not).

That being said, there is a GLCanvas object that allows you to do whatever you want in terms of GL rendering; see: https://github.com/wjakob/nanogui/blob/master/include/nanogui/glcanvas.h.

So, it appears to be more of a framework than a library.  To port your application, you need to think of it in terms of NanoGUI widgets.  In particular, whatever you're rendering, think of that as being a GLCanvas widget.

The difficulty of integration will depend on how large your application is and to what extent it is already tied to a different framework.  It may be worth learning NanoGUI in and of itself *first* (i.e., creating some simple test apps from scratch using it), so that you can get a handle on how best to merge your logic into it.

By the way, it is indeed a lovely-looking GUI, thanks for bringing it to attention :)

Comment: I am reading this as an answer that says 'NO, you cant use nanogui without GLFW.' -  Definitely an answer. =)